# How are typeof and sizeof Implemented

Tags: c#

I want to know how the `typeof` and `sizeof` keywords are implemented.

What if I want to implement my own `'x'of()` expression like `timeof(object)` where `object` contains a `DateTime` as one of it's properties or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is no. `typeof` and `sizeof` are part of the C# language, and you cannot (directly) add expressions like them. The normal way of doing what you're asking would be to simply access the property:

```
DateTime time = myObject.SomeDateTimeProperty;
```

You could make a method to do this (although it wouldn't make sense for such a trivial thing). E.g. if you used an interface:

```
public interface ICreateTime
{
    DateTime CreateTime { get; }
}

public DateTime TimeOf(ICreateTime myObject)
{
    return myObject.CreateTime;
}
```

To be more specific: `typeof` and `sizeof` aren't *implemented* in the same way you implement methods. Instead, `typeof` translates to `ldtoken [type]` and `call System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle` [IL instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), and `sizeof` becomes a constant. E.g.

```
Type t = typeof(int);
int s = sizeof(int);
```

Compiles to:

```
IL_0001:  ldtoken     System.Int32
IL_0006:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_000B:  stloc.0     // t
IL_000C:  ldc.i4.4    // the constant 4, typed as a 4-byte integer
IL_000D:  stloc.1     // s
```

Comment: Gotta love answers with IL code.  Can't get more precise than that! +1

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I would not recommend doing this even if it was possible.

`typeof` and `sizeof` are both methods that return information relevant to the compiler.  Getting the time of an object is accessing a property and not a compiler attribute.

If you have an object that has a `DateTime` you should be accessing it using:

```
object.DateTimeProperty
```